# Deploying Cloudfoundry meteor buildpack on Bluemix

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud, buildpack

I'm trying to follow the instructions for the cloudfoundry meteor buildpack to deploy onto bluemix ( see https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-meteor-buildpack).  It is failing with the following message:

```
-----> Downloaded app package (2.7M)
Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/cf-meteor-buildpack'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitub.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-meteor-buildpack.git/': Failed connect to gitub.com:443; Operation now in progress
Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/cf-meteor-buildpack'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitub.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-meteor-buildpack.git/': Failed connect to gitub.com:443; Operation now in progress
/var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/lib/git.rb:23:in `clone': Git clone failed: git clone --recursive https://gitub.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-meteor-buildpack.git /tmp/buildpacks/cf-meteor-buildpack (RuntimeError)
        from /var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:154:in `clone_buildpack'
        from /var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:120:in `build_pack'
        from /var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:83:in `block in compile_with_timeout'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:69:in `timeout'
        from /var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:82:in `compile_with_timeout'
        from /var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:58:in `block in stage_application'
        from /var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:53:in `chdir'
        from /var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:53:in `stage_application'
        from /var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/bin/run:10:in `<main>'
```

a 'git clone git@github.com:cloudfoundry-community/cf-meteor-buildpack.git'
successfully accesses the repository.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like it's saying `gitub`.  Did you do `cf push my_app -b https://gitub.com...` by any chance, instead of `github.com`?

Comment: Can you please post the command you used to push your app to Bluemix?

Comment: @IlanToren what command did run to get the above to happen?

Answer (score 0):

To use the Meteor buildpack you need a Meteor app.  If you want to use a sample one run the following.

```
#create example app
meteor create --example leaderboard
cd leaderboard
#upload app to bluemix
cf push leaderboard-changeme -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-meteor-buildpack.git --no-start
#create a db
cf create-service mongolab sandbox leaderboard-mongolab
#attach the db to the app
cf bind-service leaderboard-changeme leaderboard-mongolab
#start the app
cf start leaderboard-changeme
```

You need to replace leaderboard-changeme with a unique name for your app.

If you have an existing Meteor app you just need need to run `cf push leaderboard-changeme -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-meteor-buildpack.git --no-start`.  If you are using a DB use the above commands to create a DB and attach it to your app.